# Feed Me: Feed inside the feed

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have just started using Feed me to import a festival schedule, and I have run into an issue with how their API is set up. The URL I have to use for the feed (with the token) outputs only a `<link>URL.xml</link>` to a temporary XML-file with a unique filename each time. So there's pretty much a feed inside the feed. Any way of getting Feed Me to look at the linked XML-file, or any other suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no current way for Feed Me to handle this I'm afraid. My best suggestion would be to write a module to fetch the XML from your first URL, parse that, find the `<link>` note, fetch and parse that, and output the XML. You'd then point Feed Me to that URL, with the actual content of the feed that's required.

It could be a Craft module, a standalone PHP script, or even JS - whatever you're comfortable work.

It's a bit of extra work, but custom development would be the only option for the moment.

EDIT: The other option you could create a template (let's say `my-feed.xml`) in your templates directory with:

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/xml;" %}

{% set params = {
    url: 'http://path.to/feed/',
    type: 'xml',
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}

{% for node in feed %}
    {# Find the node that contains the link #}
    {% set link = node.myLinkNode %}

    {# Get the raw data and output it #}
    {% set xml = craft.feedme.getDataTypes().getRawData(link) %}

    {{ xml }}
```

Comment: I see, could you give me a very quick summary on how you would solve this with JS? No code, just a few words to push me in the right direction. I was hoping that I could create a separate feed and save the xml as an asset, but it looks like Feed Me only handles image files.

Comment: When I mention JS, I'm probably referring to server-side JS with Node, doing the same thing, fetching, parsing, then fetching, parsing again. Any language you'd be comfortable with, but just needs to be a "middle-man" between your original feed and Feed Me. I've also just added another method above

Comment: Is craft.feedme.getDataTypes().getRawData() something that should work out of the box?